# How to implement an array of TextView objects in a for loop?

Tags: android, for-loop, optimization, textview

I want to minimise the code by using for loop with TextView objects a,b,c,d,e as elements of an array. Both for findViewById and setOnClickListener implementations. Any actionable walkthrough for this particular coding is really appreciated!^__^

- The following is how I usually do the TextView implementations. But I
  am tired of writing so many lines needlessly.

  TextView a,b,c,d,e;

  ```
      a=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.A);
      b=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.B);
      c=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.C);
      d=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.D);
      e=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.E);

      a.setOnClickListener(this);
      b.setOnClickListener(this);
      c.setOnClickListener(this);
      d.setOnClickListener(this);
      e.setOnClickListener(this);
  ```
- My question is if I can use a loop to set all the already initialized
  TextView objects to call setOnClickListener() without any trouble as
  shown below:

  ```
  TextView a,b,c,d,e;

  a=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.A);
  b=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.B);
  c=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.C);
  d=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.D);
  e=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.E);
  ```

  TextView[] textViews = {a, b, c, d, e};

  ```
  for (int count = 0; count < textViews.length; count++) {
      textViews[count].setOnClickListener(this);
  }
  ```

**

- All I want to know is how to initialize the TextView objects
  a,b,c,d,e in the same way, I showed to setOnClickListener for them? Something like this,

  ```
  TextView[] textViews = {a, b, c, d, e};

  int[] textViewIds = {R.id.a, R.id.b, R.id.c, R.id.d, R.id.e};

  for (int count = 0; count < textViews.length; count++) {
      textViews[count] = (TextView)findViewById(textViewIds[count]);
  }
  ```

**

Comment: Put the ids into a list/array and loop over them?

Comment: yup. I would agree with @bub

Answer (score 2, accepted):

//Declare view objects as global variables in the beginning of a class

```
View v_home, v_earning, v_rating, v_account;
```

//Create view array for views and int array for view IDs

```
View[] views ={v_home, v_earning, v_rating, v_account};
int[] viewsID ={R.id.v_home, R.id.v_earning, R.id.v_rating, R.id.v_account};
```

//Then findViewById and setOnClickListener inside for loop

```
for (int v=0;v<views.length;v++){
        views[v] = findViewById(viewsID[v]);
        views[v].setOnClickListener(this);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

This is how I would write it (I dont have a compiler here so sorry for mistakes)

```
ArrayList<TextView> textViews = new ArrayList<TextView>();

int[] tvIds = {R.id.A,R.id.B,R.id.C,R.id.D,R.id.E};

for(int index= 0; index<tvIds.length/* or .count forgot sorry*/; index++){   

 TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(tvIds[index]));
 tv.setOnClickListener(this);

 textViews.add(tv);

}
```

Or you could use what @Hank Moody answered, butterknife is pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using ButterKnife for views binding, and it have a great ways to do what you want.

First of all you can bind views in List

```
@BindViews({ R.id.first_name, R.id.middle_name, R.id.last_name })
List<TextView> nameViews;
```

Then you can apply diffrent operations to this list with "Action", like this:

```
static final ButterKnife.Action<View> SET_CLICK = new ButterKnife.Action<View>() {
@Override
public void apply(View view, int index) {
    view.setOnClickListener(....listener);
  }
};
```

And then apply this ACTION

```
ButterKnife.apply(nameViews, DISABLE);
```

See examples [here](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/)

UPD: if you are using Kotlin, see [Kotter Knife](https://github.com/JakeWharton/kotterknife#kotter-knife)